# Would this implementation of sorting considered insertion sorting?

Tags: java, sorting

Is this implementation of insertion considered correct? This is a little different from some other examples I have seen.

```
public static int[] insertionSort(int[] numbers) {
    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        int index = i;
        for (int j = i-1; j >= 0 ; j--) {
            if (numbers[index] < numbers[j]) {
                int temp = numbers[index];
                numbers[index] = numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = temp;
                index--;
            }
        }

    }


    return numbers;
```

}

Comment: Test it, then you have the answer.

Comment: I should gave clarified, it works but I wanted to know if the implementation was proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is right, it should work and basically it is insertion sort, you are right. However, your algorithm will make unnecessary iterations with current implementation.

The inner loop will go through all the values which lie left to the `i` even if we already found the place to insert. As a result, your `index` value will point to the correct place, but the loop will go further, but the `if` condition won't be satisfied until the next `i` value.

To fix this you can just add the next:

```
else {
  break;
}
```

It should finish the inner loop and go to the next value of the outer loop. However, it would be even better to replace inner loop with `while` to make the code more readable.

As for the complexity, your current code will work with O(n^2) complexity even for the sorted array. With such enhancement it still will be working on O(n^2) in average, but for the best case it will be improved to O(n).